# QTreeWidget editItem fails with "edit: editing failed"

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtreewidget

I have a `QTreeWidgetItem` added to a `QTreeWidget`:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->trwPairs);
item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```

If the item is edited, I want to do a few checks on the new value:

```
Pairs::Pairs(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::Pairs)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  connect(this->ui->trwPairs, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)), this, SLOT(Validate(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)));
}

void Pairs::Validate(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int column)
{
  if (item->text(column).toInt() < 1)
  {
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", QString("Node ID ") + item->text(column) +  " is invalid.");
    ui->trwPairs->editItem(item, column);
  }
}
```

Naturally, if it's less than 1, it catches it, and gives me the message box. However, printed to `cerr` is `edit: editing failed` and the item is not in edit mode. What am I missing?

Comment: So far I can confirm this. I did a small example on my Mac using Qt 4.8 and I also get "edit: editing failed" on the stderr. Have to further investigate, did you already search the Qt source for this string?

Comment: It seems to be connected somehow to the flags. If I set them again in validate, before calling editItem(..) the warning keeps popping up.

Comment: @Nils I searched Google 5-6 pages deep on a number of search strings, nothing useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stepping through it in the debugger reveals the following:

In quabstractitemview.cpp line false is returned on line 3953. Somehow it looks like your item is still in editing state and you are trying to edit it again or something.

```
bool QAbstractItemViewPrivate::shouldEdit(QAbstractItemView::EditTrigger trigger,
                                          const QModelIndex &index) const
{
// ..
    if (state == QAbstractItemView::EditingState)
      return false;
}
```

IIRC I had a similar problem with tables with multiple lines per cell. Check out the classes `QAbstractItemDelegate` views have item delegates which allow you to control which editor is used and how it behaves. I believe by default the QLineEdit is used. Editors like QLineEdit can have validators which control how the data is validated, in your case reject it if the numerical value is < 0. But I think you have to use the model / view classes and implement your own model for that. The Qt documentation for `QTreeWidget::setItemWidget(..)` says:

> This function should only be used to display static content in the place of a tree widget item. If you want to display custom dynamic content or implement a custom editor widget, use `QTreeView` and subclass `QItemDelegate` instead.

I am not sure however if there is a simpler way to do this using the widget classes.

Comment: The primary reason I use the `QTreeWidget` is for the simplicity, especially since I have a number of them scattered throughout the application. Switching to `QTreeView` really isn't much of an option. I'd rather just have a "Edit Item" button that popped up a small dialog, or something to that effect instead.

Comment: Is there a way I can tell the item to no longer be in edit mode? What about letting the application `processEvents()`?

Comment: Well, I answered my own question: `processEvents()` is a no.

Comment: Well, I've devised a solution. If it's invalid, put the item texts back into the line edits where they came from, remove the item, and force the creation of a new pair, following the text boxes' validator rules.

Answer (score 6):

The problem could be, that you are setting the flags for your items in a very strange way.
Simply enable both item-selection, and edit:

```
item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable);
```

Comment: What is strange the way flags are set in the example above?

Comment: This solution worked for me! Who knew my item wasn't "IsEnabled" enough for it to be editable? Everything else seemed to be working like a normal enabled widget...

Comment: I have a python implementation, in which I set the flags when overriding a `QAbstractTableModel` which already does this. This solution did not work for me.

Comment: @EduardoReis if you figure it out, feel free to post a more modern answer, I posted this in 2012, and haven't touched QT in almost a decade :(

Comment: I did a bit of investigation (1 hour or so) trying to get through this. Right now I am postponing figuring this out. I hope to come back to this later at some point.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue where I was attempting to edit the subsequent column upon receiving the `itemChanged` signal. Based on Nils' analysis that the item was still in the edit state, I changed the signal connection type to [QueuedConnection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), which allowed the item to leave the state before re-entering it.

Comment: Did it work? I haven't worked on this project in a while, so I'm not really able to implement/test myself.

Comment: Yes, this solution worked for me, although I then had to fix other parts of my code which were making bad assumptions about the signal call order. (BTW, thanks for fixing my markup, user987339 - as you can see I'm new to this)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I'd get the 'edit: editing failed' error when invoking edit() via a shortcut key.  I was passing currentIndex() to edit(), but I wasn't checking that the correct column of the selected row was current.  I only had the first column editable, so if I had clicked the row (but in any other column) and then invoked my edit key I'd get the error.

I was able to solve my problem by passing the result of sibling(currentIndex().row(), 0) to edit() instead.