# PyQt validity check on QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I'm building a QTreeWidget where I'm implementing adding new item and renaming functionality. I'd like to check the validity of the new name given by user, including:

1. the name can only contain a list of valid characters. This is achieved already by adding a `QRegExpValidator` to a subclassed `QItemDelegate`, and assigning the new delegate to the `QTreeWidget`.
2. the name can't conflict with its siblings. This I don't know now to achieve.

Here is my current attempt:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QItemDelegate, QTreeWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit,\
        QMainWindow, QWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRegExp, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRegExpValidator


class TreeWidgetDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)
        reg=QRegExp('[A-z0-9\[\]_-]+')
        vd=QRegExpValidator(reg)

        editor.setValidator(vd)
        return editor


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        frame=QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(frame)
        hl=QVBoxLayout()
        frame.setLayout(hl)

        self.tree=QTreeWidget(self)
        mydele=TreeWidgetDelegate()
        self.tree.setItemDelegate(mydele)
        hl.addWidget(self.tree)

        # add treewidgetitems
        for ii in range(5):
            item=QTreeWidgetItem([str(ii),])
            self.tree.addTopLevelItem(item)

        self.tree.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.rename)
        self.tree.itemChanged.connect(self.checkString)

        dele=self.tree.itemDelegate()
        print('dele',dele)

        self.show()

    def rename(self):
        item=self.tree.selectedItems()
        if item:
            item=item[0]
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)
            self.tree.scrollToItem(item)
            self.tree.editItem(item)

    def checkString(self,item,column):
        text=item.data(0,column)
        print('newname:',text)

        siblings=[self.tree.topLevelItem(ii).data(0,0) for ii in \
                range(self.tree.topLevelItemCount())]
        print('siblings:',siblings)

        if text in siblings:
            print('invalid name')

            # this gives "edit: editing failed"
            self.tree.editItem(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     form = MainWindow()
     form.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In particular, I'm connecting `tree.itemChanged.connect(self.checkString)`, and `checkString()` checks name conflicts. However, when conflict detected I don't know how to revert to the old name and re-enter into the edit mode and let user rename again. The `tree.editItem(item)` would throw an error

```
edit: editing failed
```

. I guess that would trigger the signal again and end up in an endless loop?

I've found [PyQt - Using Multiple Validators for Item Delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076345/pyqt-using-multiple-validators-for-item-delegates) related, but no answer is given, only a suggestion in the comment that one should subclass `QValidator` to handle name conflict detection in the same regex. No idea how to do this, the validator is created and assigned before those `QTreeWidgetItems`, isn't it?

Also this question [Make QTreeWidgetItem unique among siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802936/make-qtreewidgetitem-unique-among-siblings). No body answered.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QItemDelegate, QTreeWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit,\
        QMainWindow, QWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRegExp, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRegExpValidator


class TreeWidgetDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)
        # allow only these chars
        reg=QRegExp('[A-z0-9\[\]_-]+')
        regvd=QRegExpValidator(reg)
        editor.setValidator(regvd)
        return editor


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
        frame=QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(frame)
        hl=QVBoxLayout()
        frame.setLayout(hl)

        self.tree=QTreeWidget(self)
        hl.addWidget(self.tree)

        # assign custom delegate to treewidget
        dele=TreeWidgetDelegate()
        self.tree.setItemDelegate(dele)

        # add treewidgetitems
        for ii in range(5):
            item=QTreeWidgetItem([str(ii)*3,])
            self.tree.addTopLevelItem(item)

        self.tree.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.rename)

        # QueuedConnection cures the editting failed issue
        self.tree.itemChanged.connect(self.checkName, Qt.QueuedConnection)

        self.show()

    def getSiblings(self,item):
        siblings=[self.tree.topLevelItem(ii).data(0,0) for ii in \
                range(self.tree.topLevelItemCount())]
        item_text=item.data(0,0)
        if item_text in siblings:
            siblings.remove(item_text)
        return siblings

    def rename(self):
        item=self.tree.selectedItems()
        if item:
            item=item[0]
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)
            self.tree.scrollToItem(item)
            self.tree.editItem(item)

    def checkName(self,item,column):
        text=item.data(0,0)
        siblings=self.getSiblings(item)
        print('checkName: slibings:', siblings)

        if text in siblings:
            print('checkName: ivalid')
            item.setData(0,0,'New_name_needed')
            self.tree.editItem(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     form = MainWindow()
     form.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It's still using a custom delegate to check for invalid characters. I tried adding the sibling conflict check in the delegate's editor, by subclassing `QValidator` and providing it the current list of siblings. However this would perform on-the-fly validation rather than post-commit validation. For instance when checking for the 'abc' v.s. 'abc' conflict, I won't be able to type 'c' after 'ab', even though I meant to type 'abcd'.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146364/qtreewidget-edititem-fails-with-edit-editing-failed) regarding the `edit: editting failed` error, and it seems that the `Qt.QueuedConnection` does the trick. So the `tree.itemChanged` is connected to a duplication check function, and if it fails the check, it prompts the user to re-enter name again. One can optionally popup a tooltip notifying the conflict.

May not be the ideal solution though.